# Нужно сделать запись одного массива в другой массив меньшей длины

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++, динамические-массивы

Пытаюсь создать новый массив и перезаписать в другой массив, но при выводе помимо перезаписи массива пихает в него мусор(массив t)
Функциями работой со строками пользоваться нельзя.
Программированием занимаюсь всего неделю, если ещё будут комментарии к написанию кода, то пишите.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

char* get_string(int* len) {
    int capacity = 1;
    char* s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    char c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n') {
        s[(*len)++] = c;
        if (*len >= capacity) {
            capacity *= 2;
            s = (char*)realloc(s, capacity * sizeof(char));
        }
        c = getchar();
    }
    s[*len] = '\0';
    return s;
}

char* obrabotka_size(int* len,char* f1,int size) {
    int capacity = 1;
    char* t = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    for (int i = 0; i < size;i++){
        t[i] = f1[i];

    }
    cout << "\nt=" << t;
    return t;
}

int  main() {
    int size=0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUSSIA");
    int len=0;
    char* f1 = get_string(&len);
    cout << "\nf1=" << f1;
    cout << "\nSIZEOF: " << sizeof(f1);
    cout << "\nSize stroki: ";
    cin >> size;
    char* f2 = obrabotka_size(&len,f1,size);
    cout << "\nf2=" << f2 << endl;
    cout << "\nf1=" << f1 << endl;
    delete[] f1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функции `get_string()` после `s=malloc` и `s=realloc` указатель `s` нужно проверять на NULL.
Чтобы избежать первоначального частого реаллокейта памяти начните хотя бы с `capacity=10`.
После работы функции `get_string()` длина равна количеству символов введенных, вы забыли про символ `'\0'`.
В функции `obrabotka_size()`:
Вы выделяете память под массив t в размере 1 байт. И потом туда копируете более длинную строку, что вызывает неопределенное поведение, скорее всего ошибку при выполнении программы.
Копирование идет в цикле до `size`, введенный с клавиатуры. Если первоначальная строка меньше введенного значения, то как минимум - после строки запишется мусор, как максимум - при чтении вы выходите за пределы выделенной памяти что приводит к неопределенному поведению программы. Если size меньше первоначальной строки, то концовка строки не копируется и не копируется символ `'\0'`.
Память выделенную через `malloc` и `realloc` освобождают при помощи `free()`, а не `delete[]`. И выделяется память под 2 массива, а освобождается 1.
Ну и по мелочи в функции `obrabotka_size()`:

- передается `*len`, но не используется
- объявляется `int capacity = 1`,но не используется
- вместо цикла с копированием лучше использовать функцию `memcpy`

Comment: Огромное вам спасибо, не знал, что при перезаписи массива в массив с меньшим количеством символов нужно указать терминальный 0.

Comment: Только если используете C-строки, которые ограничиваются 0. Также `sizeof()` возвращает размер строки, не учитывая символ 0. Т.е. если строка "abc" то `sizeof()` вернет 3, а в памяти строка занимает 4 байта.